# Does this root system come from a Lie group?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

We have two reduced root systems $\Psi \supsetneq \Phi$ in a real vector space $V$ such that $\Phi$ is the root system of a Lie group (the dual Lie algebra of whose maximal torus is $V$), but all we know about $\Psi$ is that the root reflections $s_\beta$ in elements $\beta \in \Psi$ preserve the weight lattice $P$ corresponding to $\Phi$.

A geometric representation theorist told me it is standard in this case that there exists some other Lie group whose root system is $\Psi$, but he didn't have a reference handy. Where can I find a citation for this result?

**Update**: I'm told in comments this is due to Serre.

**Additional question**: Given this setup, can I arrange it so that the group whose root system is $\Psi$ contains that whose root system is $\Phi$?

Comment: All reduced root systems come from some (semisimple) Lie group, via Serre's construction of the Lie algebra with that root system.

Comment: Serre did this! Thank you! I feel like I should have known that. One more question (which should perhaps go into the statement): given this can I arrange that the group whose root system is $\Psi$ contain that whose root system is $\Phi$?

Comment: I found this reference, which I have not read, but which may be useful to you: Wallach, Nolan R.
On maximal subsystems of root systems. 
Canad. J. Math. 20 1968 555–574.